# Not able to render Product facets component in the browser

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I tried to create filters for PLP Page. I have created a Product Filters Component and mapped with CMS ProductFacets Component. I am able to see the page slot in network call as well as in elements tab. But still not able to render the component in browser.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation or a code sample for the community to help faster.